# Beam stateful timer creates window?

Tags: streaming, apache-beam

We have a pipeline that does processing per kay elements with a global window(until some point).

After initial steps and mapping, we have a stateful step that stores the state of the key for future events with a similar key to enrich them.

And we have a timer associated with this state set for 1 week to clear the state because at this point the window is global and we don't want to accumulate states forever.

Code sample:

```
  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(
      ProcessContext c,
      @StateId("testState") ValueState<String> testState,
      @TimerId("expiry") Timer expiryTimer) {
    // processing logic

    // if statement - we found value to store {
      testState.write(testValue);
      expiryTimer.offset(Interval).setRelative();
   // processing logic
    c.output(KV.of(key, event));
  }
  
  @OnTimer("expiry")
  public void onExpiry(
      OnTimerContext context,
      @StateId("testState") ValueState<String> testState) {
    testState.clear();
  }
```

Despite that, we output all elements within the process element method, and in the "on timer" function we only clear the state it seems that it creates a "window" because we can't see any output before the interval for onExpiry passes(it configured for 1 week).

I thought we should be able to group elements after a stateful step without waiting for a timer to trigger. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that if you use PROCESSING_TIME timer by default it holds an output watermark on the value of the input element.
this is the dock that describes this behavior https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#timers
However, it's a bit vague, but the source code comments helped:

If the output timestamp has not been explicitly set then the default output timestamp per TimeDomain is:

- TimeDomain.EVENT_TIME: the firing time of this new timer.
- TimeDomain.PROCESSING_TIME: current element's timestamp or current timer's output timestamp.
- TimeDomain.SYNCHRONIZED_PROCESSING_TIME: current element's timestamp or current timer's output timestamp.